# Screen name validation in Liferay

Tags: validation, liferay, hook, liferay-6, liferay-aui

I am creating the users by site admin programatically by using `UserLocalServiceUtil.addUser()` method. Now how can I validate the screen name similar to existing system validation. Is there any API method call to validate the screen name?

```
<aui:input name="screenName">
<aui:validator name="required"></aui:validator>
</aui:input>
```

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

Liferay has Screenname validation by default, you dont have to validate it. If screenname is incorrect the API will throw an exception, all u have to do is catch the exception and add a session message

Comment: But I am creating my users programatically, so I have created my own user form. now how can I catch the exception and show the exception message before submitting my form

Comment: Even the API addUser has validation for screen name

Comment: So can you please suggest me how can I get the exception display it on my custom user details form

Comment: try using this   `<liferay-ui:error exception="<%= UserScreenNameException.class %>" focusField="screenName" message="please-enter-a-valid-screen-name" />`

Comment: I tried your suggestion. But I am not be able to catch the exception and display on UI. Do I need to give the value for exception message key? My input tag name also "screenName". Any suggestions please..

Comment: Hi use this API for adding User `UserLocalServiceUtil.addUser(creatorUserId, companyId, autoPassword, password1, password2, autoScreenName, screenName, emailAddress, facebookId, openId, locale, firstName, middleName, lastName, prefixId, suffixId, male, birthdayMonth, birthdayDay, birthdayYear, jobTitle, groupIds, organizationIds, roleIds, userGroupIds, sendEmail, serviceContext)`

Comment: Yes I am using the same API method to save the user info

Comment: have u put autoScreenName to false

Comment: Yes. I make it as false